# Dependency on a different package inside a project - Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a project with two packages. Let's call it Package1 and Package2. Package1 has a method that invokes a method in Package2. How do I set dependency in Maven? If I just run the test in Package 1 from pom.xml it just says "package Package2 does not exist" and "Cannot find symbol"

how do I solve this issue?

```
Project
   |
   -----------> Package 1
   |
   -----------> Package 2
```

Comment: by package you mean java package or what exactly ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi : Yes Java package in eclipse

Comment: if both Java package are under same project they should be accessible with proper `import `

Comment: @JigarJoshi : Ok. what if the Package2 extends a class from a different project? In that case I should be using an internal repo to store that jar and create a dependency right?

Comment: wait you are confusing dependency and Java package

Comment: @JigarJoshi : You answered my question. in your second response. My other comment was a different question. I understand that if both packages are in the same project they should be visible/accessible. But what if one of the class in a package invokes a method that's in a different project?

Comment: then that different (maven) project needs to be added as dependency from your caller project

Comment: So in that case I should create a Jar and put it in local repo and then add it as a dependency right?

Comment: yes - you don't have to do it maven will do it for you, just configure it properly

Comment: I will put it as answer for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both classes are in same Maven project but under different Java package they should be accessible via proper import and access visibility,

if you mean those are two different maven projects, then you need to mark required project as dependency in caller project